# Is it safe to use macros in R?

Tags: r, macros

I have written some macros in R using the `defmacro` function from the `gtools` package:

```
#' IfLen macro
#' 
#' Check whether a object has non-zero length, and 
#' eval expression accordingly.
#' 
#' @param df An object which can be passed to \code{length}
#' @param body1 If \code{length(df)} is not zero, then this clause is evaluated, otherwise, body2 is evaluated.
#' @param body2 See above.
#' @importFrom gtools defmacro
#' 
#' @examples 
#' ifLen(c(1, 2), { print('yes!') }, {print("no!")})
#' 
#' @author kaiyin
#' @export
ifLen = gtools::defmacro(df, body1, body2 = {}, expr = {
            if(length(df) != 0) {
                body1
            } else {
                body2
            }
        })

#' IfLet macro
#' 
#' Eval expression x, assign it to a variable, and if that is TRUE, continue
#' to eval expression1, otherwise eval expression2. Inspired by the clojure 
#' \code{if-let} macro.
#' 
#' @param sym_str a string that will be converted to a symbol to hold value of \code{x}
#' @param x the predicate to be evalueated, and to be assigned to a temporary variable as described in \code{sym_str}
#' @param body1 expression to be evaluated when the temporary variable is TRUE.
#' @param body2 expression to be evaluated when the temporary variable is FALSE.
#' @importFrom gtools defmacro
#' 
#' @examples 
#' ifLet("..temp..", TRUE, {print(paste("true.", as.character(..temp..)))}, 
#'      {print(paste("false.", as.character(..temp..)))})
#' 
#' @author kaiyin
#' @export
ifLet = gtools::defmacro(sym_str, x, body1, body2={}, expr = {
            stopifnot(is.character(sym_str))
            stopifnot(length(sym_str) == 1)
            assign(sym_str, x)
            if(eval(as.symbol(sym_str))) {
                body1
            } else {
                body2
            }
        })

#' IfLetLen macro
#' 
#' Similar to ifLet, but conditioned on whether the length of 
#' the result of \code{eval(x)} is 0.
#' 
#' 
#' @param x the predicate to be evalueated, and to be assigned to a temporary var called \code{..temp..}
#' @param body1 expression to be evaluated when \code{..temp..} is TRUE.
#' @param body2 expression to be evaluated when \code{..temp..} is FALSE.
#' @importFrom gtools defmacro
#' 
#' @examples 
#' ifLetLen("..temp..", 1:3, {print(paste("true.", as.character(..temp..)))}, 
#'      {print(paste("false.", as.character(..temp..)))})
#' 
#' @author kaiyin
#' @export
ifLetLen = gtools::defmacro(sym_str, x, body1, body2={}, expr = {
            stopifnot(is.character(sym_str))
            stopifnot(length(sym_str) == 1)
            assign(sym_str, x)
            ifLen(eval(as.symbol(sym_str)), {
                body1
            }, {
                body2
            })
        })
```

Is there any danger in using them?

Comment: Never even heard of them. I take it they generate code on the fly. Why would you use these instead of a function, especially given R's powerful abilities to look at its own code?

Comment: There is the potential danger that macros don't have their own environment.  See the Thomas Lumley R-news article mentioned on the help page ([PDF Warning](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2001-3.pdf)) for more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course you have to be careful. Macros do not have their own environments.

Simple example f(x,y) = (x+y)^2:

```
m1 <- defmacro(x, y, expr = {
  x <- x + y
  x*x
})
```

Executing `m1` will change the input variables in the calling environment:

```
> x <- 1
> y <- 2
> m1(x, y)
[1] 9
> x
[1] 3
> y
[1] 2
```

Normal R functions behave differently:

```
f1 <- function(x, y) {
  x <- x + y
  x*x
}

> x <- 1
> y <- 2
> f1(x, y)
[1] 9
> x
[1] 1
> y
[1] 2
```

Comment: Nicely illustrated. Could you also have a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30562653/defmacro-that-uses-local-variables-in-r