# defmacro that uses local variables in R

Tags: r, macros

Here is the code from http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2001-3.pdf :

```
defmacro <- function(..., expr){
    expr <- substitute(expr)
    a <- substitute(list(...))[-1]
    ## process the argument list
    nn <- names(a)
    if (is.null(nn)) nn <- rep("", length(a))
    nn
    for(i in seq(length=length(a))) {
        if (nn[i] == "") {
            nn[i] <- paste(a[[i]])
            msg <- paste(a[[i]], "not supplied")
            a[[i]] <- substitute(stop(foo),
                    list(foo = msg))
            print(a)
        }
    }
    names(a) = nn
    a = as.list(a)
    ff = eval(substitute( 
                    function() { 
                        tmp = substitute(body)
#                       # new environment to eval expr
#                       private_env = new.env()
#                       pf = parent.frame()
#                       for(arg_name in names(a)) {
#                           private_env[[a]] = pf[[a]]
#                       }
#                       eval(tmp, private_env)
                        eval(tmp, parent.frame())
                    }, 
                    list(body = expr)))
    formals(ff) = a
    mm = match.call()
    mm$expr = NULL
    mm[[1]] = as.name("macro")
    mm_src = c(deparse(mm), deparse(expr))
    attr(ff, "source") = mm_src
    ff
}
setna = defmacro(a, b, values, expr = {a$b[a$b %in% values] = NA; a})
dat = data.frame(x = 1:4, y = rep(-9, 4))
setna(dat, y, -9)
dat
```

The author challenges readers to come up with an new defmacro that uses local variables instead of eval in the parent frame (which could be dangerous since it could modify objects in the parent frame).

I tried to create a new environment and copy variables from the parent environment, and eval the function body there (code commented out), but the result is that it does not eval the body at all.

Could anyone help?

@bergant suggests that `eval(tmp, new.env())` will do, and indeed it works when macros are not nested, but here we have a problem:

```
#' TODO: doc
#' @export 
defmacro <- function(..., expr){
    expr <- substitute(expr)
    a <- substitute(list(...))[-1]
    ## process the argument list
    nn <- names(a)
    if (is.null(nn)) nn <- rep("", length(a))
    nn
    for(i in seq(length=length(a))) {
        if (nn[i] == "") {
            nn[i] <- paste(a[[i]])
            msg <- paste(a[[i]], "not supplied")
            a[[i]] <- substitute(stop(foo),
                    list(foo = msg))
            print(a)
        }
    }
    names(a) = nn
    a = as.list(a)
    ff = eval(substitute( 
                    function() { 
                        tmp = substitute(body)
                        eval(tmp, parent.frame())
                    }, 
                    list(body = expr)))
    formals(ff) = a
    mm = match.call()
    mm$expr = NULL
    mm[[1]] = as.name("macro")
    mm_src = c(deparse(mm), deparse(expr))
    attr(ff, "source") = mm_src
    ff
}


#' IfLen macro
#' 
#' Check whether a object has non-zero length, and 
#' eval expression accordingly.
#' 
#' @param df An object which can be passed to \code{length}
#' @param body1 If \code{length(df)} is not zero, then this clause is evaluated, otherwise, body2 is evaluated.
#' @param body2 See above.
#' 
#' @examples 
#' ifLen(c(1, 2), { print('yes!') }, {print("no!")})
#' 
#' @author kaiyin
#' @export
ifLen = defmacro(df, body1, body2 = {}, expr = {
            if(length(df) != 0) {
                body1
            } else {
                body2
            }
        })

#' IfLet macro
#' 
#' Eval expression x, assign it to a variable, and if that is TRUE, continue
#' to eval expression1, otherwise eval expression2. Inspired by the clojure 
#' \code{if-let} macro.
#' 
#' @param sym_str a string that will be converted to a symbol to hold value of \code{x}
#' @param x the predicate to be evalueated, and to be assigned to a temporary variable as described in \code{sym_str}
#' @param body1 expression to be evaluated when the temporary variable is TRUE.
#' @param body2 expression to be evaluated when the temporary variable is FALSE.
#' 
#' @examples 
#' ifLet(..temp.., TRUE, {print(paste("true.", as.character(..temp..)))}, 
#'      {print(paste("false.", as.character(..temp..)))})
#' ifLet("..temp..", TRUE, {print(paste("true.", as.character(..temp..)))}, 
#'      {print(paste("false.", as.character(..temp..)))})
#' 
#' @author kaiyin
#' @export
ifLet = defmacro(sym_str, x, body1, body2={}, expr = {
            stopifnot(is.character(sym_str))
            stopifnot(length(sym_str) == 1)
            assign(sym_str, x)
            if(eval(as.symbol(sym_str))) {
                body1
            } else {
                body2
            }
        })

#
#setMethod("ifLet",
#       signature(sym = "character", x = "ANY", body1 = "ANY", body2 = "ANY"),
#       function(sym, x, body1, body2 = {}) {
#           e = new.env()
#           sym_str = deparse(substitute(sym))
#           ifLet(sym_str, x, body1, body2)
#       })
#
##' TODO: doc
##' @export
#setMethod("ifLet",
#       signature(sym = "character", x = "ANY", body1 = "ANY", body2 = "ANY"),
#       function(sym, x, body1, body2 = {}) {
#           stopifnot(length(sym) == 1)
#           e = new.env()
#           assign(sym, x, envir = e)
#           if(e[[sym]]) {
#               eval(substitute(body1), e, parent.frame())
#           } else {
#               eval(substitute(body2), e, parent.frame())
#           }
#       })










#' IfLetLen macro
#' 
#' Similar to ifLet, but conditioned on whether the length of 
#' the result of \code{eval(x)} is 0.
#' 
#' 
#' @param x the predicate to be evalueated, and to be assigned to a temporary var called \code{..temp..}
#' @param body1 expression to be evaluated when \code{..temp..} is TRUE.
#' @param body2 expression to be evaluated when \code{..temp..} is FALSE.
#' 
#' @examples 
#' ifLetLen("..temp..", 1:3, {print(paste("true.", as.character(..temp..)))}, 
#'      {print(paste("false.", as.character(..temp..)))})
#' 
#' @author kaiyin
#' @export
ifLetLen = defmacro(sym_str, x, body1, body2={}, expr = {
            stopifnot(is.character(sym_str))
            stopifnot(length(sym_str) == 1)
            assign(sym_str, x)
            ifLen(eval(as.symbol(sym_str)), {
                body1
            }, {
                body2
            })
        })
```

If you run this test:

```
ifLetLen("..temp..", 1:3, {print(paste("true.", as.character(..temp..)))}, 
        {print(paste("false.", as.character(..temp..)))})
```

You will get an `object not found error`.

Comment: To execute the function in a separate environment, you can change the original `defmacro` just by changing `eval(tmp, parent.frame())` to `eval(tmp, new.env())`. The resulting function will use the arguments but will not change them. 

The question is - why would you need such a toothless tiger? A macro is supposed to change its arguments. (Not discussing here if it is a good idea). I think the original paper is more concerned with temporary variables inside macros. This is more complicated, because you would have to interpret the expression (now it is just passed to a function body).

Comment: I think the problem is the args of the function `ff` are introduced after the definition of `ff` itself (in `formals(ff) = a`), thus making it difficult to copy those values from parent frame, so `ff` is practically pass-by-reference. You can `eval(tmp, new.env())`, but you will get the `objcet not found` error, since the new environment is empty.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Is it about the same example (setna)?

Comment: Ah, my bad. Indeed, `eval(tmp, new.env))` works. Could you write up an answer? I would happily accept.

Comment: I want this because I don't want to accidentally overwrite variables in the parent frame.

Comment: Oh, no. It still doesn't work. See my edit.

Comment: Yes, if you want a chain of macro functions you have to take care of environment chain. See answer.

Comment: Does the `defmacro` function in the Rcmdr package do what you need?

Comment: @BondedDust It is the same as in gtools defmacro (creates functions that execute the expression in  parent.frame)

Answer (score 2):

You could add the environment as an attribute to the `defmacro`:

```
defmacro <- function(..., expr, env = parent.frame()){
  expr <- substitute(expr)
  a <- substitute(list(...))[-1]
  ## process the argument list
  nn <- names(a)
  if (is.null(nn)) nn <- rep("", length(a))
  nn
  for(i in seq(length=length(a))) {
    if (nn[i] == "") {
      nn[i] <- paste(a[[i]])
      msg <- paste(a[[i]], "not supplied")
      a[[i]] <- substitute(stop(foo),
                           list(foo = msg))
      print(a)
    }
  }
  names(a) = nn
  a = as.list(a)
  ff = eval(substitute( 
    function() { 
      tmp = substitute(body)
      eval(tmp, env)
    }, 
    list(body = expr)))
  formals(ff) = a
  mm = match.call()
  mm$expr = NULL
  mm[[1]] = as.name("macro")
  mm_src = c(deparse(mm), deparse(expr))
  attr(ff, "source") = mm_src
  ff
}
```

Here we use `new.env`:

```
ifLen = defmacro(df, body1, body2 = {}, expr = {
  if(length(df) != 0) {
    body1
  } else {
    body2
  }
}, env = new.env())
```

But here we are not:

```
ifLetLen = defmacro(sym_str, x, body1, body2={}, expr = {
  stopifnot(is.character(sym_str))
  stopifnot(length(sym_str) == 1)
  assign(sym_str, x)
  ifLen(eval(as.symbol(sym_str)), {
    body1
  }, {
    body2
  })
})

ifLetLen("..temp..", 1:3, {print(paste("true.", as.character(..temp..)))}, 
     {print(paste("false.", as.character(..temp..))); xxx <- 69})

# [1] "true. 1" "true. 2" "true. 3"
```

The first example:

```
setna = defmacro(a, b, values, expr = {a$b[a$b %in% values] = NA; a}, env = new.env())
dat = data.frame(x = 1:4, y = rep(-9, 4))

> setna(dat, y, -9)
#   x  y
# 1 1 NA
# 2 2 NA
# 3 3 NA
# 4 4 NA
> dat
#   x  y
# 1 1 -9
# 2 2 -9
# 3 3 -9
# 4 4 -9
```

The problem with the proposed solution is that you have to take care about environments (what is visible to what function and where the expressions evaluate). I don't find it very transparent as a programming tool.

Note: It doesn't solve the problem of local variables (from the original paper) - it just puts everything in separate environment (as typical R functions do anyhow).